# Django Do I need to take any step for secure my user password?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I setup an password reset system in my django website. Where user first need to submit his email address then my website sending an password rest code to his email. He need to be enter his verification code and new password in password reset page. If he entered right verification code then his password will be change and redirect to login page.
I have few question:

1. is there any security risk in my password reset system?
2. How `.set_password()` working for save user password? does it using any encryption method?
3. **Most important question**:  can user change his user_id during changing password? if yes then how to stop him to change password password if user_id changed?

here is my code:

the first function sending verification code to user email:

```
def ForgetPasswordSendCode(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       email = request.POST["email"]
       User = get_user_model()
       if not User.objects.filter(email=email).first():
           messages.success(request, "Invalid mail")
           return redirect('members:reset-password') 
       user_obj = User.objects.get(email=email)
       
       reset_code = str(rand_number_mail())
      
       
       profile_obj = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user_obj)
       profile_obj.forget_password_token = reset_code 
       profile_obj.save()


       current_site = get_current_site(request)
       subject = 'Password Reset Code'
       context = {
                    'user_first_name':  user_obj.first_name ,
                    'user_last_name':  user_obj.last_name ,
                    'domain': current_site.domain,
                    'reset_code': reset_code
                 
                }
       html_body = render_to_string('mail/resetpassword-mail.html', context)
       to_email = request.POST["email"] 
       email = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=subject,from_email='noreply@farhyn.com',to=[to_email]) 
       email.attach_alternative(html_body, "text/html") 
       email.send(fail_silently=False)
      
       messages.success(request, "password reset code sent to your email address")
       return redirect('members:change-password')     
    return render(request, 'members/password_reset_form.html')
```

This second function  changing user password. User need to be enter his verification code and new password.

```
def ChangePassWordPage(request):
    User = get_user_model()
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            
            forget_password_token = request.POST["forget_password_token"]
            password1 =  request.POST["password1"]
            password2 =  request.POST["password2"]
           
            if not UserProfile.objects.filter(forget_password_token=forget_password_token):
                messages.warning(request, "Invalid Code. Enter the correct code without any space")
            if password1 != password2:
                    messages.warning(request,"The two password fields didn’t match")
                    return redirect('members:change-password')
            user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(forget_password_token=forget_password_token)
            user_id = user_profile.user_id
            user_obj = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            if password1 == password2:
                user_obj.set_password(password1)
                user_obj.save()
                reset_code = str(rand_number_mail())
                user_profile.forget_password_token = reset_code
                user_profile.save()

                messages.success(request,"Your password sucessfully changed")
                return redirect('members:login') 
    
    except Exception as e:
        print('wrong user')

     
         
    return render(request,'members/password_change.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. Django system is pretty safe if used correctly.
If you planning to do some customizations you really need to know what you are doing.
Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/) from Django: